# authenticate function in django always give's me none?

Tags: python, django, authentication

i have this problem .. authenticate function in django give me none while passing username and password 
here is my model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class myUserExtensionManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, TypeOfUser, password=None):
        if not username:
            return ValueError("user must have username")
        if not email:
            return ValueError("user must have an email address")
        if not TypeOfUser:
            return ValueError("user must have type novice or expert")
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            TypeOfUser=TypeOfUser,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, TypeOfUser):
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            TypeOfUser=TypeOfUser
        )
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


# Create your models here.
class UserExtensionApi(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    TypeOfUser = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'  # for using for login
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'TypeOfUser']
    Manager = myUserExtensionManager()
    objects = myUserExtensionManager()

    def __str__(self):
       return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):  # permation
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_prems(self, app_label):  # they permation if they admin
        return True


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

and i import the obtain_auth_token from restframework django and this is the url file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', Registration_view, name="register"),
    path('signIn/', obtain_auth_token, name="signIn"),


]
```

finally i'm sending the username and password from reactjs using axios and i'm sure that the data is received in django but the result of authenticate function is always give's me None and i don't know why

Comment: I don't see a function named `authenticate` in the code you posted.

Comment: this function is implemented inside obtaine_auth_token .. that's mean when i send  the data to url (signIn)  it will go to obtain_auth_token that inside her authenticate function